# no desktop after 12.10 update to 3.5.0-22 generic

Tags: updates

After 12.10 update (Jan 15/2013) my desktop has changed in ways I cannot explain.  There is only the wallpaper, but the screen resolution is 600x400.  No unity, no menu bar. I can bring up a terminal, in 600x400 res'n. I can ctrl-alt-del to logout.  After logout, I get a menu bar with the only option to shutdown or login, again in 600x400 res'n.  The previous version (3.5.0-21) operates perfectly.

What to do?

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed nvidia drivers from nvidia site in earlier kernel? If so please download from [here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-310.32-driver.html) & install. You have to do it whenever there is a kernel update.

If you used `additional drivers` in earlier kernel use followings,

Re install nvidia drivers using following commands

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install nvidia-current
sudo apt-get install nvidia-settings
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.  BUT, my X11 folder has no xorg.conf file.  So, what to do now?

Comment: what if you use the old kernel from grub? it is under advanced option? waht is your graphics card? you can post `lspci | grep VGA`

Comment: 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G92 [GeForce 9800 GT] (rev a2).  yes, I can use the older kernal (3.5.0-21) listed under grub advanced options on boot screen. thanks for your help and attention!

Comment: CAN ANYONE HELP ME TO GET THE UPDATE WORKING PROPERLY, PLEASE?  Thank you.

Comment: updated. Sorry for being late

Comment: thanks for comment. Unfortunately, the reinstalls do not work for latest updates.   After trial and error for many days (countless hours), I conclude the nvidia drivers have a basic and profound conflict with Ubuntu.  What has worked now for me is to use Synaptic (via terminal) to select the "Xorg" server under the additional drivers tab.  Xorg may not yet fully exploit the nvidia card, but at least it works well enough for  most things (though I have not tried games). I have now an operable PC again. Thanks for alerting me to the problem of video drivers!